# Standing Water In Shower Drain

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have an upstairs shower that when I remove the "drain cover" (10 hours after the shower was used) there is standing water 3 - 4 inches in the drain.

I assume this means there is a clog or a block somewhere in the drain, and this might be where the drain actually starts to curve or twist because it is upstairs and the plumbing is between floors.  What prelim steps do I need to take to try to clear this block?

Things I've already tried:

1. Boiling Water
2. Your drain clog removers from box store
3. Vinegar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking into the P-trap, which is normal to have standing water in it.

It is designed to do so.

The P-trap function is to prevent smells from swage line going back.

Is it clogged ?

Take a large cup and pore water in it. How fast does it go away ?

On the other hand shower drains are notorious for hair clogs.

For that use simple plastic drain snake (about 20 inches long) and poke it out.

Preventive measure: Get a shower drain cover the prevents hairs going in.

Comment: When we first cut the shower on, we get a strong odor of raw sewage.  I just poured 64 oz of water down the drain and the water came up a bit but never filled into the shower.  I'll also add that my wife said that sometimes when she is in the shower, and washing her hair, the bubbles from the shampoo come up from the drain and into the shower a little

Comment: @user2676140 read my edited answer. It sounds like you do not have heavy clog, maybe some restriction. It is common for P-trap to dry out (no water in it) it is then when you get the sewage smell. Remedy for that is keep the p-trap filled

Comment: @user2676140 tell your wife Bubbles FLOT :)

Comment: Depending on how much shampoo is used bubbles can float on top of water in the drain,  if there is no puddle of water on the shower floor under the bubbles the drain is working correctly.